# fontconfig doesn't recognize new fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

Installed fontconfig 2.13.1 on Void Linux, and several fonts through guix (so, not a *normal* setup).

Fonts are in `~/.guix-profile/share/fonts`.

I created the following file in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

  <dir>/home/daf/.guix-profile/share/fonts</dir>

</fontconfig>
```

I have installed several monospaced fonts:

[image]

However, the only fonts which fontconfig appears to be aware of are some Ubuntu fonts which I installed and have *already removed*.

[image]

How do I get fontconfig to update it's cache *correctly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to run `fc-cache -r`, which is the "really force cache reconstruction" switch.

:rolls-eyes: